# Why do we create a new user for programs (like git) when we install git on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, git

I was reading up on how to install git on a VPS Linux server.  The fist step listed in to create a new user for git (which is often named 'git'.) I am fairly new to Linux server administration and I am a bit baffled by the idea of creating new users specifically for programs.  It seems that the program itself becomes a user and is regarded as a user by the system, separate from the current human user.

Why is this done and how should I perceive this new user?  I'm trying to get away from an old mindset of user uses programs in order to accept the broader concept of user that is employed by Linux.

Will all GIT related activities need to be performed while logged in as the 'git' user (such as push and pull?)

Comment: Could you move this question to Server Fault please?

Answer (score 5):

It is a security measure. Programs like the git shell and a git server can be run as that user. Specific, minimal permissions needed for those programs can be granted to that user.

You can read more here http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server